# Monitoring JMS queues in clustered JMS on Weblogic 10.3.4

Tags: oracle, jms, weblogic, cluster-computing

I have Weblogic 10.3.4 with a cluster of 2 managed servers, each with a JMS server. I also have a clustered JMS module with several "Uniform Distributed Queue"s. I have verified via a simple Java class that my JMS cluster does work when going through a clustered t3 URL.

However, I would like to monitor these clustered JMS queues and look at their messages in the Weblogic console. I know with a non-clustered JMS setup, I can go into the JMS module, then into the JMS queue, then to Monitoring, then to "Show Messages" as I see a destination there. However, in my clustered setup, I don't see a destination in the similar location. I know that my JMS cluster does work after some effort and assistance, but is there something else I may have missed in the configuration? I would like to view the number and contents of messages in my clustered JMS setup.